# Conditions (or areas of math) under which an infinite amount of elements is said to be continuous

Tags: continuity

I'm looking for info on continuity and discontinuity in maths, and especially on the conditions, definitions, areas of maths etc under which a continuity (e.g. a line) is taken to be strictly equivalent to an infinite amount of discontinuous elements (e.g. points). There is the obvious definition in which a set (?) is continuous if between any two elements there is yet another; but is this everything for all areas of mathematics, or is there any further debate, current or historical?

(By the way, I'm not sure about the terminology. I have little training in maths, would just like some pointers to learn more about how mathematicians think about continuity in various senses.)

Comment: Continuity applies to functions not sets. You seem to be hinting at the idea of a continuum in which case your "obvious" definition is false because the rational numbers do not form a continuum.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean here. I'm not a set theorist but as far as I know, continuity refers typically to functions, not sets. Also, when you say "a set is continuous if between any two elements there is yet another" is not right. The rational numbers satisfy this property but contain no intervals so I don't think they would qualify as "continuous"

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure about the terminology. Should have been clearer: I have little training in maths, would just like some pointers to learn more about how mathematicians think about continuity in general.

Answer (score 0):

A historical example of what you seek was an analysis of continuity by Richard Dedekind.  Start with an infinite line, drawn horizontally left-to-right.  He noted that, if you choose a point on the line, it partitions the line into two sets of points, such that all of the points in one set lie to the left of all of the points in the other set, and likewise all of the points in the other set lie to the right of all of the points in the first set *[actually either of these assertions is provable given the other]*; the chosen point may be put into either set.  After thinking long and hard, Dedekind concluded that what made the line continuous was *exactly the converse of this statement*, i.e: IF a line is partitioned into two sets, such that all of the points in one set lie to the left of all of the points in the other set (etc), THEN there is a unique point [which may be in either set] that establishes this partition *[i.e it is between the two sets (if you leave it out of both)]*.

If you need to go beyond continuity of a line, you should be looking into the basics of Topology.